# OffLine interactive world map

Tags: dictionary, mediawiki, offline

Any world map that are available offline without connecting to the net ?
and have the ability to add pins or color etc....

In short, would like to use the application in a internal wiki but cannot find anything that isn't connected to the net.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching for something like [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com).

Comment: Thank you, I will have to try this out but looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options if you look at OpenStreetMap. The OpenStreetMap-Wiki is quite helpful for finding suitable stuff.

Check: [Offline Openstreepmap Wikipage](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap)

Or maybe directly [OpenStreetMap in a Box](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap-in-a-Box)

It all depends on how much effort you are willing to put into this.
You can setup your own internal render server or you can just use prerenderd map tiles.

Do you want slippy maps (use open layers!) or just some static images (download map tiles using [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net))?

Comment: All I require is a world map with the countries divided with borders(meaning lines) hopefully be able to see the name of the countries.... with that I can start adding information over it...